# Ref Spec for Branch Sources in Jenkins Job to build PR and branch

Tags: git, github, jenkins, sonarqube

I have Jenkins server integrated with Github and sonarqube.

Now I want to use sonarqube to scan my develop branch and pull request (Only which is submitted to develop branch).

so I config the Ref Spec like this:

**+refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop**

Discover branches
Exclude branches that are also filed as PRs

now I find that when a Pull request is submited to developer branch, it will trigger jenkins build, and also the developer branch, but the feature branch also trigger the jenkins job. So how I should write the Ref Spec?  Can anyone help me! Thank you!

[jenkins screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVyJq.png)
[jenkins job config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFrXb.png)

Comment: is it just a feature branch that triggers the job besides develop branch or every other branches that has a change pushed?

Comment: every feature branch in the PR request to develop branch will trigger the build

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your configuration?

Comment: @dempti I upload the configuration screen, please help to check.